# Interface, Protocol & Abstract class

Tags: java, c++, class, virtual-functions

While studying about virtual functions I came across the three terms -
**Interface, Protocols, Abstract Class.**

Can anyone please explain the **differences** between them?

Comment: Surely you were able to find some definition of these terms. So what specifically is unclear about those that we should explain?

Comment: please let us know what exactly you confused about.

Comment: Consult with Stroustrup's glossary - http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html. If something is unclear, ask here.

Comment: In the link SChepurin provided, abstract class has been defined as a class defining an interface only. So is there no difference between the two?
In other places, I found that both were defined as a class which cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Abstract Class and Interfaces are treated syntactically and semantically different in the Java and C++ languages, if you don't pick one language or the other you may get mixed messages...Unless you want a BROAD definition, in that case read a beginning textbook in the language of your choice.

Comment: *Interface* is a general concept, the *abstract class* is a mean to implement this concept in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain difference between `abstract class` and `interface`.

 **1. interface** : It is a group of methods which have no bodies defined in interface. That means, in interface you can just declare the method, can't define the bodies. The body must be define in derived class.

 **2. Abstract class** : It is a hybrid of interface and class. In which some methods are declared with bodies and some methods are declared as abstract. Abstract means methods are declared in class,but not defined in class, just like interface. But in abstract class you can have methods with default behavior which is not possible in interface. In derived class all abstract methods must be defined or derived class should declare abstract.

Answer (score 1):

**Interface** : 
An interface is a collection of abstract methods. A class implements an interface, thereby inheriting the abstract methods of the interface.
**Abstract Class** : 
An abstract class in Java is a class that contains one or more abstract methods, which are simply method declarations without a body — that is, without executable code that implements the class or method. An abstract method is like a prototype for a method, declaring the method’s return type and parameter list but not providing an actual implementation of the method.
**NOTE** : don't know about protocol